# How to Display two tables data (child and parent table) on a JSP page in one table using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I am working on a project which is based on online shopping web application. In this project i am using Hibernate 4.3 and Spring MVC 3.1. I have two tables one is Order table(orderid, customerid, dateorderplaced, description ) and second one is Customers(Parent table) table. 
I wanna display complete details of order and customer name according foreign key of order table(customerid), I am able to display only customer id but not customer-name on jsp page.

Orders Table:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pib`.`orders`;
CREATE TABLE  `pib`.`orders` (
`orderid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`customerid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`dateorderplaced` datetime default NULL,
`orderdetails` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`orderid`),
KEY `FK_orders_1` (`customerid`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerid`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Customers table:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pib`.`customers`;
CREATE TABLE  `pib`.`customers` (
`customerid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(45) default NULL,
`lastname` varchar(45) default NULL,
`loginname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`loginpassword` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`mobile` varchar(13) default NULL,
`address` varchar(45) default NULL,
`city` varchar(45) default NULL,
`state` varchar(45) default NULL,
`pincode` varchar(45) default NULL,
`createddate` date default NULL,
`role` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`customerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Order.java :-

```
public class Orders{
private Integer orderid;
 private Customers customers;
 private Date dateorderplaced;
 private String orderdetails;
//setters n getters
}
```

Cutomers.java :-

```
public class Customers  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer customerid;
 private String firstname;
 private String lastname;
 private String loginname;
 private String loginpassword;
 private String email;
 private String mobile;
 private String address;
 private String city;
 private String state;
 private String pincode;
 private Date createddate;
 private String role;
// setters n getters
}
```

AdminOrderController.java :-

```
@Controller
public class AdminOrderController {
OrdersDAO ordersDAO;
CustomersDAO customersDAO;
@RequestMapping(value = "/vieworders.htm")
public ModelAndView prepareOrderList(){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addAllObjects(prepareOrderModel());
    mav.setViewName("admin/vieworders");
    return mav;
}
```

guyzz i am trying to display on jsp page is orderid , customer's firstname and lastname or other fields of order table. Hope you guys understand what i wanna do. Thanks in advance.

```
public Map prepareOrderModel(){
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("orderList", ordersDAO.findAll());
    //map.put("customersList", customersDAO.findAll());
    return map;
}

<table>
        <tbody>
        <% i=0; %>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Date</th>

        </tr>
          <c:forEach items="${orderList}" var="ol">
        <tr>
        <td><%= ++i %></td>
        <td>${ol.orderid}</td>
        <td>${ol.customer}</td>
        <!-- <td>${ol.firstname}</td>
        <td>${ol.cutomers.firstname}</td> -->
        <td>${ol.dateorderplaced}</td>
       </tr>
       </c:foreach> </table>
```

Comment: It would be better to show us the `jsp` code and the `prepareOrderModel()` method code instead of your table map.

Comment: @VPK    public Map prepareOrderModel(){
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("orderList", ordersDAO.findAll());
        //map.put("customersList", customersDAO.findAll());
        return map;
    } 
thnx for responce

Comment: are you getting value in `${ol.dateorderplaced}`? Try this ${ol.customers.firstname} instead of ${custName}.

Comment: @VPK yess i am getting this value.

Comment: @VPK 
i already tried this possibility. but not working.

Comment: In your updated question there is a typo, `${"ol.customer"}`, please remove double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is ${custName}?   Maybe it should be ${ol.custName} or ${ol.customer.custName} or something

Comment: There is no variable custName in jsp. If you loop over orderList and use var="ol" so all data should be in ol and start with ${ol. Please check if ordersDao.findAll() return order with initialized customers property.

Comment: So Customers object exist in Orders objects and has all necessary properties set? Hibernate set data and there is no LazyInitalization?

Comment: yepp, all properties are set, i also post Controller Class and prepareOrderModel classes. please check it. i think there is a another way to get customers class properties like firstname , lastname etc.

Comment: Maybe it is something obvious but if you check customers data during debugging then it should be ok because when you try to check field in customers then hibernate fetch this object and data and it looks like all data are set. But if you fetch orders by ordersDAO.findAll() and Orders object don't have Customers set as fetchMode=eager then Customers will be only proxy without data. And ${ol.customers.firstname} throw LazyInitializationException.  There is also other option - no Customers in database or wrong customer id?